# Get group names using the ConnectApi

Tags: apex, chatter

How do I get both the names and the ids of all the groups using apex?

Or, since I know the name of the group I'm looking for, how can I get the id of a specific group based on its name?

I'm looking at [this api](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterGroups_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterGroups_getGroups).

Apparently `ConnectApi.getGroups > group.information.title` isn't the name of the group, nor does that give you the id of the group.

I could use `ConnectApi.searchGroups`, , but that returns the same thing as `getGroups`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ConnectApi.​Chatter​Group​Detail](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_connectapi_output_GroupDetail.htm) is a subclass of [ConnectApi.ChatterGroup](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_connectapi_output_chatter_group.htm), which is where the "name" and "id" properties are. So instead of looking at group.information.title, look at group.name and group.id. (Actually, the "id" property is in the [ConnectApi.ActorWithId](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_connectapi_output_actorWithIdOutput.htm) class, but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to use ConnectAPI, this can be done using simple SOQL.
Select id,name from CollaborationGroup